# Oracle - Procedure to merge with insert, update and delete

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle19c

I need to create a procedure to treat this case in the most performative way possible (is an extremely large amount of data).

I have a table called `ORDER_A` that every day receives a full load (its truncated, and all records are inserted again).
I have a table called `ORDER_B` which is a copy of `ORDER_A`, containing the same data and some additional control dates.
I also have a table `MANAGER` to save start and finish date, and if the procedure is running.

After all inserts are done in `ORDER_A`, i want to execute a procedure that, for each record on `ORDER_A`, must looks for a record with the same identifier (primary key: `order_id`) in table B.

- If a record exists with the same order_id, and any of the other columns have changed, an update must be performed on table B
- If a record exists with the same `order_id`, and no values ​​in the other columns have been modified, nothing should be performed, the record must remain the same in table B.
- If there is no record with the same order_id, it must be inserted in table B.
- If there is a record on `ORDER_B` that no longer exists on `ORDER_A` (it was deleted), the column "flag_deleted" must be updated to  "1".

My tables are like this

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER_A
(
    ORDER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ORDER_CODE VARCHAR2(50),
    ORDER_STATUS VARCHAR2(20),
    ORDER_USER_ID NUMBER,
    ORDER_DATE TIMESTAMP(6),
    CHECKSUM_CODE VARCHAR2(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER_B
(
    ORDER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ORDER_CODE VARCHAR2(50),
    ORDER_STATUS VARCHAR2(20),
    ORDER_USER_ID NUMBER,
    ORDER_DATE TIMESTAMP(6)
    INSERT_AT TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP(6),
    CHECKSUM_CODE VARCHAR2(40),
    FLAG_DELETED NUMBER(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID)
);

-- index on checksum column for both tables
CREATE INDEX idx_cksum on ORDER_A (CHECKSUM_CODE ASC);
CREATE INDEX idx_cksum on ORDER_B (CHECKSUM_CODE ASC);


-- Manager table
CREATE TABLE MANAGER
(
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(40),
    PROCEDURE_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
    START_TS TIMESTAMP(6),
    FINISH_TS TIMESTAMP(6),
    IS_RUNNING NUMBER(1)
);
```

I'm thinking in something like this procedure below, but I'm not sure if it's the best way and how to deal with the delete case

```
create or replace procedure MERGE_DATA_ORDER
DECLARE
 is_running number;
 ex_running EXCEPTION;
BEGIN

SELECT IS_RUNNING INTO is_running FROM MANAGER WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME = 'MERGE_DATA_ORDER';

IF is_running = 1 
   then RAISE ex_running

ELSE

-- Update the flag on manager table
UPDATE MANAGER SET IS_RUNNING = 1, START_TS = SYSTIMESTAMP WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME = 'MERGE_DATA_ORDER';
COMMIT;
        

-- update all records with a checksum using STANDARD_HASH with MD5
    UPDATE ORDER_A
        SET CHECKSUM_CODE =
            STANDARD_HASH
            (
                ORDER_ID ||
                ORDER_CODE ||
                ORDER_STATUS ||
                ORDER_USER_ID ||
                ORDER_DATE,
                'MD5'
            );          
        COMMIT;
        
-- then, I do a MERGE operation, using the checksum as a comparator 
 merge into ORDER_B b
    using (select a.* from  ORDER_A a) m
        on (m.ORDER_ID = b.ORDER_ID)
    when matched then
      update
        set 
            b.ORDER_ID = m.ORDER_ID,
            b.ORDER_CODE = m.ORDER_CODE,
            b.ORDER_STATUS = m.ORDER_STATUS,
            b.ORDER_USER_ID = m.ORDER_USER_ID,
            b.ORDER_DATE = m.ORDER_DATE,            
            b.COD_CHECKSUM = m.COD_CHECKSUM,
            b.DAT_UPDATE = SYSTIMESTAMP
      where b.CHECKSUM_CODE <> m.CHECKSUM_CODE

    when not matched then
      insert (
            b.ORDER_ID,
            b.ORDER_CODE,
            b.ORDER_STATUS,
            b.ORDER_USER_ID,
            b.ORDER_DATE,
            b.COD_CHECKSUM
            )
        values (
            m.ORDER_ID,
            m.ORDER_CODE,
            m.ORDER_STATUS,
            m.ORDER_USER_ID,
            m.ORDER_DATE,
            m.COD_CHECKSUM
            );

   END IF;

-- set the flag to 0   
   UPDATE MANAGER SET IS_RUNNING = 0, FINISH_TS = SYSTIMESTAMP WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME = 'MERGE_DATA_ORDER';
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I need some help to complete this code, performance tips and deal with the delete issue;

Comment: The delete will require a separate command; no way to make that part of the merge. Something like `delete from order_b where order_id not in (select order_id from order_a);` Also, be sure to carry over your `CHECKSUM_CODE` from `ORDER_A` to `ORDER_B` when you insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this as a single statement as part of the data load. Let's assume that ORDER_A has been loaded (but I will comment on that later). Then you can define the result of the insert/update by doing a full outer join between ORDER_A and ORDER_B, and the use a CASE statement to project the "correct" value from ORDER_A or ORDER_B. Similarly you can project the FLAG_DELTED. It would look something like this. In this example, I am skipping the MD5, but this could be added if really needed - more on that later too

```
select
       case 
       when ( b.order_id is null ) then a.order_id
       else case when (
            b.ORDER_ID      != m.ORDER_ID or
            b.ORDER_CODE    != m.ORDER_CODE or
            b.ORDER_STATUS  != m.ORDER_STATUS or
            b.ORDER_USER_ID != m.ORDER_USER_ID or
            b.ORDER_DATE    != m.ORDER_DATE     or    
            b.DAT_UPDATE    != SYSTIMESTAMP ) then b.order_id else a.order_id end
        end as newOrder_id
     , case when ( b.order_id is null ) then a.order_code
       else case when (
            b.ORDER_ID      != m.ORDER_ID or
            b.ORDER_CODE    != m.ORDER_CODE or
            b.ORDER_STATUS  != m.ORDER_STATUS or
            b.ORDER_USER_ID != m.ORDER_USER_ID or
            b.ORDER_DATE    != m.ORDER_DATE     or    
            b.DAT_UPDATE    != SYSTIMESTAMP ) then b.order_code else a.order_code end
        end as newOrder_code 
     , case when ( b.order_id is null ) then a.order_status
       else case when (
            b.ORDER_ID      != m.ORDER_ID or
            b.ORDER_CODE    != m.ORDER_CODE or
            b.ORDER_STATUS  != m.ORDER_STATUS or
            b.ORDER_USER_ID != m.ORDER_USER_ID or
            b.ORDER_DATE    != m.ORDER_DATE     or    
            b.DAT_UPDATE    != SYSTIMESTAMP ) then b.order_status else a.order_status end
        end as newOrder_status
/* etc... ( Repeat for all projected columns ) 
   Then for the flag_deleted column */
     , case when ( a.order_id is null ) then 1
            when ( b.order_id is null ) then 0
            else b.flag_deleted 
       end as newFlag_deleted
from Order_b b
full outer join Order_a a
on b.order_id = a.order_id
```

It may be possible that ORDER_A could be an external table, so then you would just need to prepend this with a

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_ORDER_A as select....
```

And then you have the results you need.

Where you a hemorrhaging performance in your example, is the update of ORDER_A. You are generating redo, undo and losing any compression benefits. You are also maintaining indexes, but indexes are not needed.
Assuming you have resources, you cab now use DIRECT PATH and parallelism, and this would scale pretty well.

Lastly, if you really do need the MD5, you need to add a special character between each column, otherwise is will be ambiguous. For example, the following woukd have the same MD5

```
COL1   COL2
AA     BBB
AAB    BB
```